# Will blackberry smartphone apps run on the Playbook?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-playbook

Will a Blackberry smartphone application written in the Java api work on the Playbook without modification?

Answer (score 5):

According to RIM, once the JDE player is released, they will have to be re-packaged which may require re-compiling, to run on the PlayBook. The same applies to Android applications. In either case you will not be able to download native JDE or Android apps and run them on the PlayBook.

Answer (score 1):

The only application SDK path that allows for BlackBerry Smartphone applications to run both on BBOS, Playbook and BlackBerry 10 is the HTML5 WebWorks SDK

**Get started** by reading the Getting Started Overview Guide
https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/what_is_a_webworks_app_1845471_11.html

You may also be interested in cloning bbUI.js, a free ui framework that works across BlackBerry devices going back to OS5. bbUI.js targets platform specific native features, like access to hardware apis, while providing a consistent feel.

**blackberry/bbUI.js**
https://github.com/blackberry/bbUI.js

Best of luck to you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, RIM has announced that they will release a virtual machine which will play your existing blackberry app. I'm not sure if developers have to re-submit their blackberry apps though.

Playbook will also support Android apps, but developers will have to recompile their apps and submit those to App World.